# Rails Controller Modify JSON Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have this method in my controller:

```
# GET /bios/1
# GET /bios/1.json

def show
 if member_session?
   @member = MemberPresenter.new(@bio.member)
   # I need something here to add a flag to the json response to signal this is a member session.
 else
  @member = MemberPresenter.new(@bio.member)
 end
end
```

I need to modify the json response to return something like:

{ member: @member, member_session: true }

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json` param for `render` functions:

```
render json: { member: @member, member_session: true }
```

But it's not the best way to render JSON in rails. I'd recommend you try to use https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you specifically want to return json all the time but here's an alternative to rendering other formats as well:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: { member: @member, flag: @member.status } }
end
```

For small and simple objects, doing this is fine, but if you had to drag the associations along, you have the choice of using a serializer, or you could override the `to_json` method to something like this.

```
# member.rb

def as_json(options = {})
  options = options.merge(
    except: [
     :updated_at,
     :created_at,
    ],     
    include: {         # Getting associations here
      address: {
        only: [:street, :zip_code],
        include: {
          neighbors: { only: :name }
          }
        }
      }
   )
  super.as_json(options)
end
```

And finally within the controller, `render json: @member.to_json` and it will pull all the associations you want with it. This is the lazy man's way of serializing aka what I do :)